# Invalid Syntax Error - Average Calculator "IF" and "WHILE"

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, syntax-error, average

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, but this is driving me up a wall. Why am I getting a Syntax error? I have to code an average calculator using a while statement, where "0" defines that the program needs to perform the calculation.

[image]
Here's the sample output my professor defined:

```
SAMPLE RUN 

Enter test score 80 

Enter test score 70 

Enter test score 90 

Enter test score 88 

Enter test score 0 

The average is 82.000%
```

Comment: `if test == '0'` isn't a valid line on it's own. What do you want to do there?

Comment: Please do not post a screenshot of your code. Copy paste your code in your question and use the formatting tools. Also, please paste the *exact* error message of where the syntax error is happening

Comment: I'm not seeing how you exit the infinite loop or why you expect to check an integer compared to a string

Comment: Sorry about that! I'll keep it in mind.

Answer (score 2):

The `if` statement in the image (please post the actual code in your question) is invalid. It needs a colon, i.e. `if test == '0':`. It also needs a body.

The sample output suggests that `0` is to terminate the loop. Check for that first, before you modify `division_integer` otherwise the average will be affected. Then, when you get a `0` *break* out of the while loop with `break`, i.e.

```
while True:
    test = int(input('Enter test score:'))
    if test == 0:
        break
    addition_integer += test
    division_integer += 1
```

Note that you are converting the input into an integer, but your test was for the *string* `"0"`. You need to test for the integer `0` as I show above.

Another point, you should use a `try/except` block when converting the input into an integer so that you can catch invalid input:

```
while True:
    try:
        test = int(input('Enter test score:'))
    except ValueError:
        print('Invalid number entered, try again.')
        continue
    # etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed your code for you. For future questions, please post your code directly in your question and indent it all by 4 spaces to properly format it.

```
addition_integer = 0
divison_integer = 0

while True:
    test = int(input("Enter test score: "))
    if test == 0:
        break
    else:
        addition_integer += test
        divison_integer += 1

print("The average is {}%".format(addition_integer/divison_integer))
```

Here's an explanation of what I did to fix this:

You were looping `while True`, which is correct, however you had no way to break out of the while loop. Your line saying `if test == '0'` would never resolve to true because you're taking the input as an `int` from the user, not to mention it was out of place and didn't have proper syntax.. What I am doing in the code above is continuing to loop until the input from the user is equal to `0` (an integer, not a string). If the user inputs `0`, then we simply break out of the loop and print the average. Until then, we continue to add the input to `addition_integer` and increment `division_integer` by 1.

All in all, you were pretty close to the solution, you just needed a few syntax changes and to be steered in the right direction as to how you can break out of an infinite loop.

Finally, here is a test using the numbers that you've provided in your question:

```
Enter test score: 80
Enter test score: 70
Enter test score: 90
Enter test score: 88
Enter test score: 0
The average is 82%
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative answer

Use a list, sum and divide. Same concept, compare test inside the while loop in order to break out of it. Also check if you get valid input that can be made an integer with a try/except.

Additionally, beware of the division by zero

```
values = [] 

while True:
    try:
        test = int(input('Enter test score:'))
        if test == 0:
            break
        values.append(test) 
    except:
        break

total = len(values)
avg = 0 if total == 0 else 1.0 * sum(values) / total 

print("The average is", avg)
```